Fluent React UI 9 - DataGridHeaderCell is blocking input of 'space'
If you use a Input component inside a DataGridHeaderCell component, you cannot type 'spaces'. If you remove the wrapping DataGridHeaderCell it works.
Can I get this to work while using DataGridHeaderCell? (see line 138 in both code examples to spot the difference)
Repro:
Doesn't block space
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Models from './models/tables'
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
    FolderRegular,
    EditRegular,
    OpenRegular,
    DocumentRegular,
    PeopleRegular,
    DocumentPdfRegular,
    VideoRegular,
    PaddingDown20Filled,
} from "@fluentui/react-icons";
import {
    PresenceBadgeStatus,
    Avatar,
    DataGridBody,
    DataGridRow,
    DataGrid,
    DataGridHeader,
    DataGridHeaderCell,
    DataGridCell,
    TableCellLayout,
    TableColumnDefinition,
    createTableColumn, Button, FluentProvider, webLightTheme, makeStyles, tokens, Title1,
    webDarkTheme,
    makeStaticStyles,
    mergeClasses,
    Title3,
    Input
} from '@fluentui/react-components';

const useStaticStyles = makeStaticStyles({
    'html, body, #root': {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        margin: '0',
        padding: '0'
    }
});


const useStyles = makeStyles({
    outerContainer: {
        height: '100%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        gap: tokens.spacingHorizontalXXXL,
        padding: tokens.spacingHorizontalXXXL,
        backgroundColor: tokens.colorBrandBackground2
    },
    container: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    gapM: {
        gap: tokens.spacingHorizontalM
    },
    row: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
    paddingM: {
        padding: tokens.spacingHorizontalM
    },
    dataGrid: {
        backgroundColor: tokens.colorBrandBackground2Hover
    },
    datagridHeader: {
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
        padding: tokens.spacingHorizontalM,
        fontSize: tokens.fontSizeBase600
    },
    datagridRow: {
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
        paddingTop: tokens.spacingHorizontalXS,
        paddingBottom: tokens.spacingHorizontalXS,
        paddingLeft: tokens.spacingHorizontalM,
        paddingRight: tokens.spacingHorizontalM,
        fontSize: tokens.fontSizeBase400,
        backgroundColor: tokens.colorNeutralBackground6
    },
    buttonRow: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    shadowBox: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        boxShadow: tokens.shadow2,
        gap: tokens.spacingHorizontalXXXL,
        padding: tokens.spacingHorizontalXXXL
    },
});

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState<Models.Item[]>([]);
    const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState<number>(0);
    const [itemFilterString, setItemFilterString] = useState<string>('');

    const columns: TableColumnDefinition<Models.Item>[] = [
        createTableColumn<Models.Item>({
            columnId: "item",
            renderHeaderCell: () => {
                return (
                    <div className={mergeClasses(classes.container, classes.gapM)}>
                        <Title3>Item</Title3>
                        <Input appearance='underline' placeholder='Filter' onChange={(ev, data) => {
                            setItemFilterString(data.value);
                        }}></Input>
                    </div>
                );
            },
            renderCell: (item: Models.Item) => {
                return (
                    <TableCellLayout>
                        {item.ItemName}
                    </TableCellLayout>
                );
            }
        })];


    const classes = useStyles();
    useStaticStyles();

    return (

        <FluentProvider theme={webDarkTheme} className={mergeClasses(classes.outerContainer)}>
            <input type='text' ></input>
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <DataGrid sortable={false} columns={columns} items={data} className={classes.dataGrid}>
                    <DataGridHeader>
                        <DataGridRow className={classes.datagridHeader}>
                            {({ renderHeaderCell }) => renderHeaderCell()}
                        </DataGridRow>
                    </DataGridHeader>
                    <DataGridBody<Models.Item>>
                        {({ item, rowId }) => (
                            <DataGridRow<Models.Item> className={classes.datagridRow}>
                                {({ renderCell }) => (
                                    <DataGridCell>{renderCell(item)}</DataGridCell>
                                )}
                            </DataGridRow>
                        )}
                    </DataGridBody>
                </DataGrid>
            </div>
        </FluentProvider >
    );
}

export default App;


Blocks space
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Models from './models/tables'
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
    FolderRegular,
    EditRegular,
    OpenRegular,
    DocumentRegular,
    PeopleRegular,
    DocumentPdfRegular,
    VideoRegular,
    PaddingDown20Filled,
} from "@fluentui/react-icons";
import {
    PresenceBadgeStatus,
    Avatar,
    DataGridBody,
    DataGridRow,
    DataGrid,
    DataGridHeader,
    DataGridHeaderCell,
    DataGridCell,
    TableCellLayout,
    TableColumnDefinition,
    createTableColumn, Button, FluentProvider, webLightTheme, makeStyles, tokens, Title1,
    webDarkTheme,
    makeStaticStyles,
    mergeClasses,
    Title3,
    Input
} from '@fluentui/react-components';

const useStaticStyles = makeStaticStyles({
    'html, body, #root': {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        margin: '0',
        padding: '0'
    }
});


const useStyles = makeStyles({
    outerContainer: {
        height: '100%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        gap: tokens.spacingHorizontalXXXL,
        padding: tokens.spacingHorizontalXXXL,
        backgroundColor: tokens.colorBrandBackground2
    },
    container: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    gapM: {
        gap: tokens.spacingHorizontalM
    },
    row: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
    paddingM: {
        padding: tokens.spacingHorizontalM
    },
    dataGrid: {
        backgroundColor: tokens.colorBrandBackground2Hover
    },
    datagridHeader: {
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
        padding: tokens.spacingHorizontalM,
        fontSize: tokens.fontSizeBase600
    },
    datagridRow: {
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
        paddingTop: tokens.spacingHorizontalXS,
        paddingBottom: tokens.spacingHorizontalXS,
        paddingLeft: tokens.spacingHorizontalM,
        paddingRight: tokens.spacingHorizontalM,
        fontSize: tokens.fontSizeBase400,
        backgroundColor: tokens.colorNeutralBackground6
    },
    buttonRow: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    shadowBox: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        boxShadow: tokens.shadow2,
        gap: tokens.spacingHorizontalXXXL,
        padding: tokens.spacingHorizontalXXXL
    },
});

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState<Models.Item[]>([]);
    const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState<number>(0);
    const [itemFilterString, setItemFilterString] = useState<string>('');

    const columns: TableColumnDefinition<Models.Item>[] = [
        createTableColumn<Models.Item>({
            columnId: "item",
            renderHeaderCell: () => {
                return (
                    <div className={mergeClasses(classes.container, classes.gapM)}>
                        <Title3>Item</Title3>
                        <Input appearance='underline' placeholder='Filter' onChange={(ev, data) => {
                            setItemFilterString(data.value);
                        }}></Input>
                    </div>
                );
            },
            renderCell: (item: Models.Item) => {
                return (
                    <TableCellLayout>
                        {item.ItemName}
                    </TableCellLayout>
                );
            }
        })];


    const classes = useStyles();
    useStaticStyles();

    return (

        <FluentProvider theme={webDarkTheme} className={mergeClasses(classes.outerContainer)}>
            <input type='text' ></input>
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <DataGrid sortable={false} columns={columns} items={data} className={classes.dataGrid}>
                    <DataGridHeader>
                        <DataGridRow className={classes.datagridHeader}>
                            {({ renderHeaderCell }) => renderHeaderCell()}
                        </DataGridRow>
                    </DataGridHeader>
                    <DataGridBody<Models.Item>>
                        {({ item, rowId }) => (
                            <DataGridRow<Models.Item> className={classes.datagridRow}>
                                {({ renderCell }) => (
                                    <DataGridCell>{renderCell(item)}</DataGridCell>
                                )}
                            </DataGridRow>
                        )}
                    </DataGridBody>
                </DataGrid>
            </div>
        </FluentProvider >
    );
}

export default App;



Thanks,
Frank
